# how to define a good/perfect New function to init any class/struct in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
    struct object {
        void Name() {}
    };
  struct ABC:object { //Note:did not declare any constructor and base class is object
    std::byte a;
    const std::string* b;
    int c;
  }
struct BCD { //Note:did not declare any constructor and none base class 
    std::byte a;
    const std::string* b;
    int c;
  }
```

i want the New function accept:

```
New<ABC>({12,"first",123});
New<ABC>(a,b,c);
New<BCD>({12,"first",123});
New<BCD>(a,b,c);
```

this is my New function define:

```
    template <class _Ty, class... _Types, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<_Ty>, int> = 0>
    auto New(std::initializer_list<std::any>&& _Args) {
        //i can get type informationof the _Ty For use GC  at here 

        return  new _Ty(std::forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
        //if need also can be record the pointer For use GC at here
    }
```

but i cound'nt got the correct result;

I use the latest VC ++ (vs2019)
So you can use the tool to provide the latest C ++ language standard.

**Why i need this function:**
i want add GC into C++ ,but i need take more type info Before allocating memory.
Actually I want to get the type information before calling operator new.This is a big plan, I think I can get the unique ID of the information (or use reflection), whether the scan type contains a set of pointers (references) and their offsets. This provides the GC with a run-time memory scan. Improve conservative GC performance. I just started planning.

Comment: what is the purpose of the function? Why not `ABC {12,"first",123};` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Actually I want to get the type information before calling operator new

Comment: what type information? I think this question would benefit from adding some words on why you want to do that. Also it is not perfectly clear what you mean with "cound'nt got the correct result;" are there compiler errors? Please include them in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 I added the problem description in the New function Code.i want add GC into C++ ,but i need take more type info Before allocating memory. This is a big plan, I think I can get the unique ID of the information (or use reflection), whether the scan type contains a set of pointers (references) and their offsets. This provides the GC with a run-time memory scan. Improve conservative GC performance. I just started planning.

Comment: i am not an expert on gc and this is more about my personal preference, but imho you better also explain it in text. I tend to ignore comments in code completely (because most comments are wrong/misleading)

Comment: What's wrong with `std::make_unique<ABC>(12,"first",123)`? Of course that uses smart pointers, while yours uses dumb pointers.

Comment: You seem to be trying to invent `std::make_unique`. At least, you could look at how that one is implemented, and make your `New` work similarly. It does *not* involve `std::initializer_list<std::any>`

Comment: You may also be interested in [Boehm's garbage collector](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  In fact, I just hope to improve the performance of bdwgc in this way.